# HDFS Clustering in swarm

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, docker-swarm

In normal docker environment HDFS clustered images like hadoop-master and hadoop-slave works fine. But when I try to run these images in swarm mode, I am facing connectivity issues. Is clustered hdfs compatible with docker swarm?
The service that I deployed is restarting and exiting continously for every 2-3 seconds.
Can someone help me in detail to implement HDFS clustering in swarm mode.
When I do docker logs conatinerid, I get

```
start sshd...
/bin/sh: 0: Can't open /bin/which
/etc/init.d/ssh: 424: .: Can't open /lib/lsb/init-functions.d/20-left-info-blocks

start serf...
Error connecting to Serf agent: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:7373: connection refused
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, you don't have `/bin/which` nor LSB support installed.

Install all prerequisites.

Comment: Can you please specify all the prerequisites in order to overcome the connectivity issues in swarm.

Comment: I can't. I don't use it.